# Why is my legend in my seaborn countplot not showing all the labels?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Seaborn countplot showing seven different animal classes:

```
g = sns.countplot(data=df, x="class_type")
plt.legend(title="Animal Type", loc="upper right", labels=["Mammal", "Bird", "Reptile", "Fish", 
                                                           "Amphibian", "Bug", "Invertebrate"])
plt.show(g)
```

which gives me this image.
[image: countplot]

as you can see, only the first label is displayed. How do I show the label for each bar, please?

this is the top (first 20 rows) of my dataframe:

```
   animal_name  hair  feathers  eggs  milk  airborne  aquatic  predator  \
0     aardvark     1         0     0     1         0        0         1   
1     antelope     1         0     0     1         0        0         0   
2         bass     0         0     1     0         0        1         1   
3         bear     1         0     0     1         0        0         1   
4         boar     1         0     0     1         0        0         1   
5      buffalo     1         0     0     1         0        0         0   
6         calf     1         0     0     1         0        0         0   
7         carp     0         0     1     0         0        1         0   
8      catfish     0         0     1     0         0        1         1   
9         cavy     1         0     0     1         0        0         0   
10     cheetah     1         0     0     1         0        0         1   
11     chicken     0         1     1     0         1        0         0   
12        chub     0         0     1     0         0        1         1   
13        clam     0         0     1     0         0        0         1   
14        crab     0         0     1     0         0        1         1   
15    crayfish     0         0     1     0         0        1         1   
16        crow     0         1     1     0         1        0         1   
17        deer     1         0     0     1         0        0         0   
18     dogfish     0         0     1     0         0        1         1   
19     dolphin     0         0     0     1         0        1         1   

    toothed  backbone  breathes  venomous  fins  legs  tail  domestic  \
0         1         1         1         0     0     4     0         0   
1         1         1         1         0     0     4     1         0   
2         1         1         0         0     1     0     1         0   
3         1         1         1         0     0     4     0         0   
4         1         1         1         0     0     4     1         0   
5         1         1         1         0     0     4     1         0   
6         1         1         1         0     0     4     1         1   
7         1         1         0         0     1     0     1         1   
8         1         1         0         0     1     0     1         0   
9         1         1         1         0     0     4     0         1   
10        1         1         1         0     0     4     1         0   
11        0         1         1         0     0     2     1         1   
12        1         1         0         0     1     0     1         0   
13        0         0         0         0     0     0     0         0   
14        0         0         0         0     0     4     0         0   
15        0         0         0         0     0     6     0         0   
16        0         1         1         0     0     2     1         0   
17        1         1         1         0     0     4     1         0   
18        1         1         0         0     1     0     1         0   
19        1         1         1         0     1     0     1         0   

    catsize  class_type  
0         1           1  
1         1           1  
2         0           4  
3         1           1  
4         1           1  
5         1           1  
6         1           1  
7         0           4  
8         0           4  
9         0           1  
10        1           1  
11        0           2  
12        0           4  
13        0           7  
14        0           7  
15        0           7  
16        0           2  
17        1           1  
18        1           4  
19        1           1
```

as you can see, it's a mix of numeric, string and one hot encoded data.

Comment: Can you share the sample of dataframe?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa sure

Comment: Can you paste `print(df.head(20))` output?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa yep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for including the sample data.

One issue seems to be that the `plt.legend()` command isn't operating on your current axis.

You can do this instead:

```
import seaborn as sns, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

ax = sns.countplot(data=df, x="class_type", hue='class_type', dodge=False) 
h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels=["Mammal", "Bird", "Reptile", "Fish", "Amphibian", "Bug", "Invertebrate"]
ax.legend(h,labels,title="Animal Type", loc="upper right") 
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

The `dodge=False` kwarg tip was found here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/871

Comment: The dodge tip was very helpful, thank you. My problem has been solved.